# Using \addplot+ and \foreach in pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have four text files with each 21 columns, and I want to plot, for each file, the first column as x, and then the 20 next columns as y. For each file, then put it all together on the same graph. It's basically 20 replicates under 4 different conditions.

I have the following code, using `\foreach`, but I'd like to make it cleaner by using `\addplot+` rather than `\addplot` with the fill argument. If I use `\addplot+` within the `\foreach` loop, then each replicate has it's own color, and it's not really what I want.

To be clear, the following code does what I want, but I'd like to hear about solutions to make it nicer.

```
\documentclass[professionalfonts,11pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Conséquences des variations du taux de croissance}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{semilogyaxis}[
            xlabel=Temps,
            ylabel={Taille de population},
            cycle list name = monokai,
            legend pos = north west
            ]
            \foreach \yindex in {2,...,20}
                \addplot[mark = none, draw = RYB1] table [y index = \yindex] {data/vardem_30.dat};
            \foreach \yindex in {2,...,20}
                \addplot[mark = none, draw = RYB2] table [y index = \yindex] {data/vardem_10.dat};
            \foreach \yindex in {2,...,20}
                \addplot[mark = none, draw = RYB3] table [y index = \yindex] {data/vardem_3.dat};
            \foreach \yindex in {2,...,20}
                \addplot[mark = none, draw = RYB4] table [y index = \yindex] {data/vardem_1.dat};
        \end{semilogyaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see the question here. Do you want to simplify the code or what kind of niceness are you after? You can put 4 `\addplot` commands under one `\foreach`. Is that what you mean by niceness? You can find the explanation for using `+` in the manual.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Your example is missing `\usepackage{pgfplots}`
- You don't neccessarily need `draw=color`, just `color` is enough
- As *percusse* said, one `foreach` loop should be enough
- You said you had 21 colums, so the loop should run to that value
- `\addplot[options]` should only execute the `options`, so you can leave out the `mark=none`. Otherwise you may specify `\pgfplotsset{every axis plot post/.append style={mark=none}}`

---

```
\documentclass[professionalfonts,11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Conséquences des variations du taux de croissance}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{semilogyaxis}
          [ xlabel=Temps,
            ylabel={Taille de population},
            cycle list name = monokai,
            legend pos = north west,
            ]
          \foreach \yindex in {2,...,21}
            {   \addplot[RYB1] table [y index = \yindex] {data/vardem_30.dat};
            \addplot[RYB2] table [y index = \yindex] {data/vardem_10.dat};
            \addplot[RYB3] table [y index = \yindex] {data/vardem_3.dat};
            \addplot[RYB4] table [y index = \yindex] {data/vardem_1.dat};
            } 
          \end{semilogyaxis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also factorize the four `\addplot` with `\foreach \name/\file in {RYB1/30,RYB2/10...`.

Comment: Thanks! This is really simpler than my code... (for some reason, I'm still thinking in C loops, so I'm used to them starting from 0...)

Comment: I know what you mean ;) Also, for `\foreach \x [count=\c] in {red,blue,white}` here `\c` starts to count from 1, which was irritating the first time I used it.