# How to apply the same coordinate calculation for many \addplot commands in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have a whole bunch of data files that contain the output of a measurement program which are all of the same multicolumn structure and that I want to plot in the same way using `pgfplots`. Some of the plots are not just plotting the data contained in the files but values calculated from several of those columns. I can achieve this by giving the `addplot` command an option `y expr = ...` with a mathematical expression to calculate as shown in the MWE below:

```
\begin{filecontents}{plot1.dat}
        x   alpha   beta
        1   0.5     3
        2   0.3     19
        3   0.7     4
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{plot2.dat}
        x   alpha   beta
        1   2       1
        2   4       3
        3   1       18
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot+ table[x=x, y expr=\thisrow{alpha}-\thisrow{beta}]{plot1.dat};
    \addplot+ table[x=x, y expr=\thisrow{alpha}-\thisrow{beta}]{plot2.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, it is quite annoying and error-prone to do this with plots of some 10+ files by just dumb-copying the `\addplot` command and exchange the file name for every one of them.

I came up with a slightly more elegant solution (thanks to [Using \addplot+ and \foreach in pgfplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68800/using-addplot-and-foreach-in-pgfplot)) using `\foreach` to iterate through the file names:

```
\begin{filecontents}{plot1.dat}
        x   alpha   beta
        1   0.5     3
        2   0.3     19
        3   0.7     4
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{plot2.dat}
        x   alpha   beta
        1   2       1
        2   4       3
        3   1       18
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \foreach \file in {1,2}
        \addplot table[x=x, y expr=\thisrow{alpha}-\thisrow{beta}]{plot\file.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This reduces complexity a bit since I only have to write the `y expr =` only once per plot, however for several separated plots I still have to copy the expression from one to the other. Therefore my question is if I can somehow define a "function" that I can just write into the options of `\begin{axis}` or `\addplot+` to be applied as coordinate calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your functions separately for each file:

```
\tikzset{%
    declare function={Function1(\x,\y)=(\x-\y);},
    declare function={Function2(\x,\y)=(\x+\y);},
    declare function={Function3(\x,\y)=(\x*\x-\x*\y);},
}
```

and then invoke the function based on the file name:

```
\addplot table[x=x, y expr={Function\file(\thisrow{alpha},\thisrow{beta})}]{plot\file.dat};
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\begin{filecontents}{plot1.dat}
        x   alpha   beta
        1   0.5     3
        2   0.3     19
        3   0.7     4
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{plot2.dat}
        x   alpha   beta
        1   2       1
        2   4       3
        3   1       18
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{plot3.dat}
        x   alpha   beta
        1   0.5     3
        2   0.3     19
        3   0.7     4
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\tikzset{%
    declare function={Function1(\x,\y)=(\x-\y);},
    declare function={Function2(\x,\y)=(\x+\y);},
    declare function={Function3(\x,\y)=(\x*\x-\x*\y);},
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \foreach \file in {1,2,3}
        \addplot table[x=x, y expr={Function\file(\thisrow{alpha},\thisrow{beta})}]{plot\file.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```